# GetState from fabric via chaincode always return empty value

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, leveldb

I built a blockchain network in `chaincode dev mode` with three organizations and six peers based on the official [chaincode example](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html). I directly deployed the chaincode example onto the blockchain network. There is no problem to invoke the chaincode in the way like `peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'`. But every time I query the ledger via chaincode in which query is implemented by `GetState (key)`, it always return `empty value`, even if I can get the key/value pair by invoking `GetStateByRange("","")` which returns all the key/value pairs. I inspected the logs from the peer where the chaincode was installed on. The logs are shown below.

```
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.670 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 961 [43697748]Received message GET_STATE from shim
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.670 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 962 [43697748]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: GET_STATE in state rea
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.670 UTC [chaincode] afterGetState -> DEBU 963 [43697748]Received GET_STATE, invoking get state from ledger
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.670 UTC [chaincode] filterError -> DEBU 964 Ignoring NoTransitionError: no transition
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.670 UTC [chaincode] func1 -> DEBU 965 [43697748] getting state for chaincode test, key , channel chainplaza
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [stateleveldb] GetState -> DEBU 966 GetState(). ns=test, key=
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] func1 -> DEBU 967 [43697748]No state associated with key: a. Sending RESPONSE with an empty payload
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] 1 -> DEBU 968 [43697748]handleGetState serial send RESPONSE
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 969 [43697748]Received message COMPLETED from shim
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 96a [43697748]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state rea
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 96b [43697748e1ea4c6f0f6af336f6c413583716c8ec1d59c10118ecfd49bf581509]HandleMessage
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 96c notifying Txid:43697748e1ea4c6f0f6af336f6c413583716c8ec1d59c10118ecfd49bf581509
    2018-01-17 09:01:26.671 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 96d Exit
```

What is weird is that `[stateleveldb] GetState -> DEBU 966 GetState(). ns=test, key=`, the `key` part is empty. In the blockchain working properly, the value of the `key` should be the parameter of `GetState(key)`.

So what kind of errors can result in such a weired situation? 
The chaincode I use can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/chaincode/chaincode_example02).

Comment: very hard to spot the problem/bug w/o seeing specific code of the chaincode, would you mind to post here an example which is not working for you? And the way how you invoke it?

Comment: @ArtemBarger Thank you. I found the root cause and I posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason by myself. It's because `fabric` uses  an `ccenv` image to build the chaincode when you instantiate your chaincode. This images has a specified version of fabric source code in it's `GOPATH` to build the chaincode. I guess the version of fabric source code in the image should be the same with the source code used to build/compile fabric(including peer/order etc.). And there is a dependency project(`github.com/miekg/pkcs11`) in the vendor of the fabric source code in the image. This project is responsible for crypto stuffs. In my chaincode project, I also vendored `github.com/miekg/pkcs11` in other chaincodes but with a different commit version. it seems it will cause conflicts. But I don't know exactly how it causes conflicts. After I removed my own vendored `pkcs11`. All the problems disapppeared.